# What is the point of sass @extend?

Tags: sass

I have been using Sass for a while and I can't get my head around of using @extend. I mean what is the point of extend if u can't extend nested selectors. In my code I have some styles that are 2 or 3 levels deep and I would like just to pass them to another selector. To use @extend I have to create special class and then extend it, what is the point you could just use @mixin?

Comment: `@extends` provides a [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) CSS output (unlike mixins), and it helps keeping your markup clean when applying the OOCSS methodology. See http://takazudo.github.io/presentation-oocss-sass/ and http://csswizardry.com/2014/01/extending-silent-classes-in-sass/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases @extend makes the css output smaller than if you would use a mixin. But the most efficient way is to put that @extend class in the html and not extend it to an element which does not have that class. Eventually the DOM might get messy, but it's faster.

Comment: Here's a pretty good answer about mixins vs extends. http://csswizardry.com/2014/11/when-to-use-extend-when-to-use-a-mixin/